# Version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found in CentOS (in file /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6)

Tags: centos, glibc, g++

I try to use a program and I get the following error.

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
```

Under /usr/lib64 the libstdc++ I see is libstdc++.so.6.0.13 (and a soft link).

With `strings libstdc++.so.6.0.13 | grep GLIBCXX` I get

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

---

With `cat /etc/redhat-release` I get

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

So the question in what should I do in order to fix that. Should I install some new packages  and if yes which ones?

Comment: I have not looked to see of they have it but have you tried EPEL

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a newer version of GCC and, if it is a separate package in CentOS, a newer version of gcc-libs. Unfortunately, I don't think such recent versions will be available in the CentOS repository.

One option would be to install the latest version of GCC for your user account only (i.e. don't install it system-wide, which will help avoid some potential headaches). You can do this pretty easily using [GSRC](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsrc), but of course you can also just download the GCC source archive and specify a non-standard directory to the `--prefix` option. Then, when you build your new software, you'll have to specify `LDFLAGS="-L /path/to/your/gcc/libs -L/usr/lib (etc)"`, `CFLAGS="-I /path/to/your/gcc/includes -I /usr/include (etc)"` and probably something like `CXX=/path/to/your/g++`. When you run the program you'll need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/gcc/libs` in your environment.

Alternatively, you can install a distro with more up-to-date software, though I understand that this is not always possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I used this link for [glibcxx_3.4.15](http://pkgs.org/download/libstdc++.so.6) and manually placed the contents to the folder required (/usr/lib folder). I was able to run gdb on my apps after that. Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Select the link under the ALT Linux tabs and download binary package (these packages are more generic and can be used on various distros).

Ex: libstdc++6-4.7.2-alt7.i586.rpm - GNU Standard C++ library

This will include libstdc++.so.6.0.17 as well as libstdc++.so.6.0.15.

Comment: Our CentOS version is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.4. So from your link the package has until libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.13) and not 3.4.15

Comment: Well, I'm using the same version of CentOS and was having the same error message. You may have not noticed but it comes with libstdc++.so.6.0.17 which includes the version you are looking for, but you can try this link too which has that exact version [glibcxx_3.4.15](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libstdc%2B%2B.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15))